# How to find the length and width using contours

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm using `cv2.arcLength()` for getting the perimeter and boundingRect for the box of the object. I can't seem to get the exact length of the rice with functions

I used a canny edge for the edges and used a contour for its areas. I can't get the length/height of the rice and its width:

[image]

Comment: Please define length?  Do you mean the long axis of the rice? If so, use cv2.minAreaRect() from the contour to get the rotated rectangle bounding box. The long dimension of the rotated rectangle will be your length.  Alternately, fit an ellipse (cv2.fitEllipse()) to each contour. The long dimension of the ellipse will be your length.  Note that you will likely need to separate touching rice grains using watershed processing.

Comment: I've got the answer thank you all I need now is to get the percentage of chalk of rice inside it.

Comment: Make a mask for each rice grain by drawing a white filled contour on a black background. Then use the mask to get the average value of the corresponding rice grain.

Comment: My problem is that the camera is not detecting the chalk from the inside of the rice grain.  So I can't make a contour out of it also

Comment: `@lisamarigondondaw` I see white interior rice grains.  Should all be partially filled so as to be visibly white?  What is wrong with unfilled grains? Is that your original image? If not, post the original image without markings.

Comment: So basically I need the lower and upper hsv is that correct? For detecting the chalk. The one with unfilled grains have lower percentage of chalk or none of it

Comment: You have not provided your input image nor your code. So we cannot suggest what to do.   Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just new to the platform. Thank you for the comments by the way

Comment: Do you still have questions? Or did you resolve everything?

Answer (score 0):

Contour length is equal to the product of the number of segments of polymer molecule(n) and its length(l).The function returns the contour information in the form of x,y,w,h . The height for a specific contour will be h and the width will be w.